# Do I have wet dreams or sweating

Tags: ghusl

I am in my early twenties. Sometimes I wake up after my alarm clock goes off without feeling anything but whenever I check my pants, I feel like part of it is either cold or wet (it is really hard in these scenarios for me to properly identify whether it is cold or wet which is confusing) but without any stains or anything. Usually, I know when I have wet dreams (in those scenarios I wake up immediately after my discharge, and there are stains in my pant as well as I can surely tell that my pants are wet).
At this stage, I am not sure whether those cold/wet scenarios are from my sweating (I do sweat at night often) or miniature versions of wet dreams. What should I do in this scenario? Do I need to perform ghusl and wash my pants? Or do I just go about performing usual daily activities

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to do ghusl because if discharge happened and you didn't know still you will be impure. To remove the doubt you should perform ghusl.